# How to remove sidebar tabs in admin grid form of magento?

Tags: magento, tabs, magento-1.7, adminhtml

I am working on Magento community edition 1.7 version.
I have a grid in admin when I click on "Add New" from this grid a form appear but it has some tabs in left side.I need to remove that tabs and want only form.

http://d.pr/i/Qa8i

app/code/community/namespace/test/Block/Adminhtml/test/Edit/Tabs.php

My code for tabs in above file is:

```
 protected function _beforeToHtml() {

    $this->addTab('form_section', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('test')->__('Book'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('test')->__('Book'),
        'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('test/adminhtml_book_edit_tab_form')->toHtml(),
    ));

    return parent::_beforeToHtml();         
}
```

Can anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Admin controller

please see **editAction**

```
$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('<module>/adminhtml_<module>_edit'))
                     ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('<module>/adminhtml_<module>_edit_tabs'));
```

remove

```
->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('<module>/adminhtml_<module>_edit_tabs'));
```

then create file name form.php in

app/code/community/namespace/test/Block/Adminhtml/test/Edit/Form.php

and paste the code in

```
class <Namespace>_<Module>_Block_Adminhtml_<Module>_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $<module>Form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id' => 'edit_form',
            'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
            'method' => 'post',
        ));
        $<module>Form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($<module>Form);

        $fieldset = $<module>Form->addFieldset('<module>_form', array(
            'legend'      => Mage::helper('<module>')->__('Item Information'),
            'class'       => 'fieldset-wide',
            )
        );

        $fieldset->addField('<module>_name', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('<module>')->__('Name'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'name',
        ));


        if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->get<Module>Data() )
        {
          $<module>Form -> setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->get<Module>Data());
          Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->get<Module>Data(null);
        } elseif ( Mage::registry('<module>_data') ) {
          $<module>Form-> setValues(Mage::registry('<module>_data')->getData());
        }
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hello check below path **app/code/community/namespace/yourmodule/Block/Adminhtml/yourmodule/Edit/Tabs.php**
checkfunction  _beforeToHtml() &  __construct(). comment those you want

Hope this help you

Comment: I already do that but it removes tabs and  form both.I need to remove only tabs not form.